# Is it common to ask for sending the ORIGINAL Diploma to HR department?

Tags: human-resources, hungary

Currently, I have received a job offer from a Hungarian company. The HR department asked me to send my original Diploma (BsC or MsC).

They say:

> No other translation is accepted but the sworn translation prepared by the Hungarian National Translation Office, here in Hungary.
>   We will take good care of it and send it back to you along with the other documents which must be submitted.

Is it a common process and shall I trust?

Comment: Honestly doesn't sound like they need the Original Copy of your Diploma. Only a certified translation prepared by the Hungarian National Translation Office. This might mean that you need to make a certified copy and send it in. There aren't many situations that would require you to send the actual original and nothing that you have provided indicates that either. If anything... if they really wanted to confirm your Diploma, they would contact your Uni directly.

Comment: **Never** send the originals - some are irreplacable... We were warned by our university that they would not replace the certificate, but could replace the grades transcript. Send them a “good” copy.

Comment: Never send originals. There's nothing about the original that provides any more proof of authenticity than a good colour photocopy. If they query it say you're happy to bring it with you when you start so they can look at it and photocopy it while you are present. Most of the time they just take a photocopy of it anyway.

Comment: @Shadowzee "We will take good care of it and send it back to you" doesn't sound like they are talking about the original to you? How?

Comment: @DetectivePikachu It never refers to the original, Only that "No other translation is accepted but the sworn translation prepared by the Hungarian National Translation Office". So in this case, it would refer to your official, paid for translation. If anything, your Official untranslated copy would be invalid.

Answer (score 6):

According to the quote you provided, they only ask for a **translation** of the diploma, done by a trusted certified third party (specifically,  the Hungarian National Translation Office). That is acceptable, and pretty much risk free.

For other details, you need to contact the company directly (possibly the HR department) to ask for details. Normally, for companies, copies are enough.

The specifics of each company are... aaa... specific... to each company. We cannot help you there.

---

Usually a simple copy of the diploma is enough for most companies. However, if the languages are very different (the language of the company and the language of the diploma), or even worse, they use completely different alphabets, then some translation is mostly mandatory.

My own example: at the company where I work now, a copy of the diploma was enough. Actually, it was a copy done with a smartphone, so not even a very good quality copy. They did the translation internally, aided by some online translation services, and asking me questions for the details that were not understandable from the automatic translation.

Comment: In addition: some times the "translation" will also involve  assertaining whether your BSc or MSc diploma will count as such in Hungary (or another country).

Comment: What do you think " We will take good care of it and send it back to you" refers to then if its not the diploma? Do you think they think OP really treasures this translation of his diploma?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a common process

Its not a common process to ask for original documents to be sent to a company,

that too over post,

and that too to an international destination.

> shall I trust?

No, don't send the original documents. Rather,

- share your concerns over sending the original copies,
- make them aware that insurance etc of the mail will not be worth the hassle if something goes wrong/ docs are lost
- search some local and online Hungarian translator companies
- check with the HR if you could use the local or online Hungarian translator company
- or if they could allow the Hungarian National Translation Office to translate your documents online, [which their website seems to suggest is possible (google translator).](http://www.offi.hu/en/node/11)